# Split database into two databases

Tags: database, split

I would like to split my database into two databases, a quick check showed that I can easily query, join, update tables across databases.

My main problem now is that to do this, I will have to do something like this.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Database1.dbo.Table1, 
       Database2.dbo.Table2
```

As you can see I have to explicit mentioned database names, which means that if database name is deployed with a different name, this code will not work anymore.

Any ideas to overcome this problem?

Comment: Why do you want to split it in first place? If you are thinking that it will make it work faster, you are most likely wrong

Comment: i have to different terminals for the application, one uses almost quarter of the database, and the other uses the whole database. and i dont want to deploy the whole database with the one that just uses quarter of it, also i dont want to create two different databases one for each terminal.

Comment: Typical solution for these problems is to use single database, but  add or use some field that allows you to constrain your queries according to the situation. You can even enforce security with that using views and giving different permissions to views (and revoking access to underlying tables).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `db_name()` to get the current database name and dynamic sql to build a dynamic query.
Something like:

```
declare @databaseName nvarchar(max) = db_name()

declare @dynamicSql nvarchar(max) = 'SELECT * FROM '+ @databaseName + '.dbo.Table1'

exec sp_executesql @dynamicSql
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, that would work but not very clean, i would prefer something wihtout dynamic sql.